# c# Converting a i.o. stream to a byte[] is slow

Tags: c#, stream

My code works great no question. The issue is that it is so slow!

If I use streamHelper to read it in bytes or use the stream.Copyto, it takes about the same time. A LONG TIME!

There has to be a faster way?

If I read the same file using FileStream from a filepath, it processes in less than 1 second.

Converting from Stream to Byte takes about 6 seconds. All help is much appreciated. Thanks

```
byte[] byteArray = null;

// Read Data from Port Monitor
Stream inputStream = Console.OpenStandardInput();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    inputStream.CopyTo(ms);
    byteArray = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: You are at the mercy of the other application and `StandardInput`... Its definitely not `CopyTo` or `ToArray` that will be causing the issue

Comment: So you think Console.OpenStandardInput(); is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely might have delay from standard input. Plus if you are re-reading data entirely, you could incrementally read instead of re-reading all at once.

Also, if the data is large, you are copying twice by using CopyTo() (which copies stream to stream) and ToArray() (which copies stream to array). Instead, you should use inputStream.Read() to directly read the data into a buffer from the original stream.

Code:

```
// Allocate a buffer the size of the whole stream
byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.Length];
// Set position at the beginning of our stream.
inputStream.Position = 0;
// Read all data into our buffer.
inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Keep in mind, some streams do not have a valid "length" property, but this is rarely the case, and I assume it isn't in your case. Just keep in mind, this *will* be faster (even if only a bit), but your bottleneck may largely come from standard input, and so this will only help so much if that is the case.

Comment: The only way I can find is to Copy the Stream(Console.OpenStandardInput) to a MemoryStream,then copy that to the array.

inputstream.Read() seems to want to read an existing byte. Can you provide more instruction using my code?

Comment: inputStream.Read(), yes, it read a specified amount of bytes into an existing buffer, at a given position. All you need to do is allocate the buffer with the correct size first. Here's an example where we allocate a buffer to the length of the stream, and read it all. I've edited my post above to include the code.

Comment: Thanks heaps. 'll give it a crack and see if it's faster.

Comment: so close: I get an error:
Stream exception - This stream does not support seek operations